# Can processed cheese cause a thickening of toenails?

Tags: contributing-factors, nails, sensitivity-intolerance

Can a thickening of ones toenails occur if toxic food, such as wrongly processed cheese, frequently is consumed? Foods that are overloaded with toxic food additives, in other words?

Comment: Why don't you revert all edits and ask a new question? You changed the question so much that answers now don't apply to your question anymore...

Comment: Can you explain why you think this would be the case? I don't understand how there could be such a causal relationship.

Comment: Neither do I. That's why I am asking the question. It was a guess to try to establish why the nail of my left big toe looked and felt funny. I had consumed processed light cheese when I thought I noticed it, but I had also consumed other things, which I don't remember now.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). If your toenail is bothering you, you might go and see your doctor. Although the question, as it is written is a general one, you are in fact asking because you need personal medical advice and we shouldn't provide that over the internet. What made you think that thickening of your toenail was diet-related in the first place? If you have some research to support your assumption, we can comment on that. Otherwise this question is sending us on a wild goose chase. The best way for you to get an answer would be to see a doctor.

Comment: Some light cheeses might be processed in ways that make them less healthy. Saw a film for some while ago about the production of a light cheese,  and I remember thinking that this is it. But, it needs of course to be proven that this is so.

Answer (score 2):

---

### Answer to the old question "Can light-cheese cause ingrown toenails":

**No**
*This Question might more be suited for Sceptic SE.*
I suffered from an ingrown toenail, but all doctors agreed that it was caused by not cutting my nails properly (I.e. I cut too much of my nail) and so the skin started to grow into my nail bed.

You will have to see a doctor about this, and the two options I know of *if there are infections caused by ingrown toenails* are surgery or to put brackets on your toe to pull it out of the nail bed.

This has nothing to do with eating habits.

EDIT:
Ingrown toenails are caused by skin being in the way of the nail.
There are two ways this can happen:
1. The skin is somewhere where it shouldn't be (i.e. growing into the nail bed if the nails has been cut too much)
Or 2. The nail being somewhere where it shouldn't be (i.e. if you had strangely curved nails)

Neither 1 nor 2 is related to eating habits or food consumption, hence the answer to your question is **No**.

See [Mayo-Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/ingrown-toenails/symptoms-causes/dxc-20273047)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53830/discussion-on-answer-by-narusan-can-light-cheese-cause-ingrown-toenails).

Comment: Could you please explain how an ingrown toenail is related to the OPs thickening toenail?

Comment: @Marzipanherz. Originally the question said "ingrown toenail". I tweaked it when I realised that my doctor's diagnosis most likely had been faulty.

Comment: @Constantthin and Narusan: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Constantthin Just for the future: It is considered good practice to *ask a new question* and not totally change the old one for exactly this reason.

Answer (score -2):

Toe-nail fungus can cause a thickening of ones toe-nails, and is "one of the most common reasons for thick toenails".

> Nail fungus is a common condition that begins as a white or yellow spot under the tip of your fingernail or toenail. As the fungal infection goes deeper, nail fungus may cause your nail to discolor, thicken and crumble at the edge. It can affect several nails. (Nail Fungus: www.mayoclinic.org)
>
> Changes in your toenails may be a sign of an underlying condition. Toenails that have grown thicker over time likely indicate a fungal infection, also known as onychomycosis. Left untreated, thick toenails can become painful. Prompt treatment is key to curing the nail fungus. Fungal infections can be difficult to cure and may require months of treatment. (Thick Toenails (Onychomycosis): www.healthline.com)
>
> If you notice that one or more of your toenails are thick, discolored, brittle, and crumbling it could be a sign that a fungal infection is causing thickened toenails. In fact, nail fungal infections (the medical name is onychomycosis) are one of the most common reasons for thick toenails.
>   Podiatrist, Dr. Kyoung Min Han says that toenail fungal infections are more common than fingernail fungus and affects around 10% of all adults in Western countries. (Thick Toenails: Causes and Effective Home Remedies: www.healthyandnaturalworld.com)

Another, less common toe-nail thickening condition is Psoriasis.

> Psoriasis can affect fingernails and toenails. Psoriasis symptoms include pitting, abnormal nail growth and discoloration. (Nail psoriasis: Can treatment or home care help?: www.mayoclinic.org)

Comment: Please add some references